# Chrome performance tool - What's going in the long task after the html has downloaded but before the HTML is parsed?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, profiling

I am trying to learn how to use the Chrome performance profiler to better optimise my applications but am finding it difficult to reason about the results I receive as they are a bit vague.

I have an application that has a small amount of HTML on it and running it in incognito mode.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  Hi
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I have set a cache control header to attempt to cache the index page in the browser to eliminate network overhead and focus only on parse/rendering however it still makes a request to the server.

Even still, the 2ms value only covers a small portion shown in the performance tools which I *assume* is network transfer.

[image]

What is this "task" doing and why is it taking so long?

[image]

Comment: Enable "Show native functions" in main devtools settings and "Timeline: show all events", "Timeine: V8 Runtime" in devtools settings experiments.